# creating sind or cosinus graph, when we have only Amplitude peak

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I would like to draw sinus (or Cosinus) curve in excel, when I have only the Amplitude peaks. How can I do?

I would like to draw something like this:

[image]

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You must give more specifications. What do you want exactly ? Either, draw a curve with three pics at given positions, without respect to the shapes of curves drawn of the graph ? (then they are an infinity: what of them you want ?) , or draw a curve with the shape as drawn on the graph ? (then, more points than the three pics must be given) , or something else ? (then we can't guess).

Comment: @JJacquelin I would like to draw three curve at given position (as peak) without respect to the shape of curves. The shape of curves are not important. only the point must be positioned as peak

Comment: Still ambiguous. Do you want to draw them with three functions, for example each one as $y_n(x)=A_n sin(B_nx+C_n)$ with $n=1$ to $3$ ? Or do you want only one function $y(x)$ which has maximums on the  given points ?

Comment: @JJacquelin the first one with n=1 to 3

Answer (score 0):

They are still an infinity of solutions, even taking account of your complementary specification : three distinct sinusoidal functions, for example : $y_n=a_n\cos(b_nx+c_n)$ with $n=1$ to $3$. So the answer below is probably not what you expect exactly. But one cannot guess.
$$y_1=0.013\cos(x)$$
$$y_2=0.011\cos(x-1)$$
$$y_3=0.025\cos(x-2)$$
Note that the abscissa were not specified. If $0$ , $1$ , $2$ are not whose expected, correct them.